# how to reset input value attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reset the value of the input once i click a date in the datepicker, my goal is to add a single date in the array once a click a date, what happening is once i click a date for the multiple times, it still holds the previous value of the input.

```
var date = new Date();
var days = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inputMultiDate").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    multidate: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  }).on("changeDate", function(){
    dates = $('#inputMultiDate').val().split(',');
    days.push(dates);
     $('#inputMultiDate').attr('value', '');  
    console.log(days);
  });;
});

<input type="text" id="inputMultiDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access the event by using datepicers onSelect:

```js
var date = new Date();
var days = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputMultiDate").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    multidate: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      dates = $('#inputMultiDate').val().split(',');
      days.push(dates);
      $('#inputMultiDate').attr('value', '');
      console.log(days);
      let value = $("#inputMultiDate").datepicker("getDate");
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="inputMultiDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick the multiple dates">
```

Comment: may i know what's the difference between "on" and "onSelect"?

Comment: .on() listens to the events of the DOM, onSelect is the event listener specifically for the datePicker as defined [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect). The documentation states, that the datepicker selection doesn't fire any events to the outside. Take a look at the [api](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and see the column events.

Comment: So instead of binding the datepicker `$("#inputMultiDate")` to an event, you can add an *event handler* directly to the specific selection event.

Comment: i also wan't to know why does the input holds the previous value even i use the attr.val('') or .val('[)?

Comment: If you want to get the current value of datepicker, use `let value = $("#inputMultiDate").datepicker("getDate");` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inputMultiDate').val('')
```

In jQuery "val" is a get function also a set function. You can set your input with val('').

Comment: i already tried this one, but the problem is it still holds the previous date of the input and store it into my array, as a result ex 0:["02-01-2019"] 1:["02-01-2019", "03-01-2019"]

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the new Date() function every time the date changes. Currently, you have one date as the page loads.

```
var date = new Date();
var days = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inputMultiDate").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    multidate: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
   }).on("changeDate", function(){
    date = new Date();
    dates = $('#inputMultiDate').val().split(',');
    days.push(dates);
    $('#inputMultiDate').attr('value', '');  
    console.log(days);
  });;
});
```

Comment: same output sir